# Update database when CSV file is updated

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I have data on a CSV file that I have imported into the DB, and display the data into my index.html as a HTML table.
**The CSV is updated frequently**

Is there anyway to update the data in the DB from the CSV file every hour or day, or even every time the file is updated?

PS: As I'm new to Django, what I do now is that I delete the whole DB and than migrate and import the file again, and I don't think that is a good way to do it.

Comment: Use your operating system's scheduling facilities. Windows: Scheduled Tasks. Posix: `cron`.

Comment: or try django celery.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements, you can write a management command and schedule a job using `cron` every hour or every day.
here is a link to read more about [How to create custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/)

```
def dummyfunc():
    tests = TEST.objects.filter(parameter = parameter)

    if tests.exist():
        test = tests[0]
        test.field = file_name
        test.save()
    else:
        test = Test.objects.create(
              field = field_name
         )
        test.save()

return test
```

Comment: Let me be more clear. I have an app named TESTS and a model named TEST, I import the CSV to TESTS.TEST  on the DB using the command{ Sqlite3.exe db.sqlite3} Does using cron enable me to updata the TESTS.TEST with latest modifications on the CSV file without having to delete the DB

Comment: Yeah sure why not you will need to write a function for this to check, you just need to filter model data by some **parameter** on existing data from the CSV file that if the **parameter** exits on the model then update the database from the file or else create a new object. I have updated also answer you will have to write something similar its just a dummy  fucntion.